ADC0834 Only Returning Zeros on Raspberry Pi 5
[
I’m having trouble with my ADC0834 setup on a Raspberry Pi 5. Despite following a guide The Guide I used, my setup only returns zeros. Here are the details:
Connections:
CLK on the chip connected to pin 18
CS on the chip connected to pin 17
DI (which I believe is bidirectional as per the guide) connected to pin 27
Middle leg of my potentiometer connected to CH0 on the chip
All VCC and GND for the potentiometers are connected
Code:
import time
import gpiod

freq = 50_000
one_cycle = 1/freq
half_cycle = one_cycle/2
val = 0

chip = gpiod.Chip('gpiochip0')
CS = chip.get_line(17)
DIO = chip.get_line(27)
CLK = chip.get_line(18)

CS.request(consumer='dev1', type=gpiod.LINE_REQ_DIR_OUT)
CLK.request(consumer='dev2', type=gpiod.LINE_REQ_DIR_OUT)
DIO.request(consumer='dev3', type=gpiod.LINE_REQ_DIR_OUT)

try:
    CS.set_value(0)
    CLK.set_value(0)

    CLK.set_value(0)
    time.sleep(half_cycle)
    DIO.set_value(1)
    CLK.set_value(1)
    time.sleep(half_cycle)

    CLK.set_value(0)
    time.sleep(half_cycle)
    DIO.set_value(1)
    CLK.set_value(1)
    time.sleep(half_cycle)

    CLK.set_value(0)
    time.sleep(half_cycle)
    DIO.set_value(0)
    DIO.release()
    DIO = chip.get_line(27)
    DIO.request(consumer='dev3', type=gpiod.LINE_REQ_DIR_IN)

    for i in range(8):
        bit = DIO.get_value()
        print(bit)
        CLK.set_value(1)
        time.sleep(half_cycle)
        CLK.set_value(0)
        time.sleep(half_cycle)

    time.sleep(2)
    CS.set_value(1)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    CS.release()
    CLK.release()
    DIO.release()

Any insights on why I’m only getting zeros would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks in advance!

Clear photos of connections made? Linux kernel version?

@joan Hello, thanks for your reply! I'm using bookworm. I've updated the original post with an image. (I think it is capped at 1 image.)

Have you tried using SPI rather than bit-banging the chip?
